# Create list with 2 columns using foreach

Tags: c#

I have a list that is just 1 row initially as such:

```
    One
    Two
    Three
    Four
    Five 
    Six
    Seven
```

I would then have the following in a list - note how I have 2 columns - first column is for odd number, second column is for even number:

```
    One     Two
    Three   Four
    Five    Six
    Seven
```

I am trying the following:

```
foreach(var item in mod)
{
    int i = 0;

    i = i + 1;
    if (i % 2 == 0) 
    {                  
        //add to list here for even number 
    }

    if (i % 2 != 0)
    {
        // add to list here for odd number
    } 
}
```

Comment: You can replace the 2nd if statement with an else statement.

Comment: I don't think you meant to declare `i` inside the loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest LINQ:

```
var odds = mod.Where((item, index) => index % 2 == 0).ToList();
var evens = mod.Where((item, index) => index % 2 == 1).ToList();
```

Comment: But this is two passes through the input list rather one. While not a big thing for this small data set it would have an impact on performance if the input list were large.

Comment: Aren't you iterating through the collection twice with this?

Comment: True, but until we know that the size is large enough to warrant it, I prefer code simplicity over speed.

Answer (score 2):

You're redeclaring `i` each time. Move the declaration outside of the foreach.

```
List<int> even = new List<int>();
List<int> odd = new List<int>();

int i = 0;
foreach (var item in mod)
{
    i = i + 1;
    if (i % 2 == 0)
    {
        even.Add(i);
    }
    else
    {
        odd.Add(i);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Previous answer had an error:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var mod = new string[] { "One", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five", "Six", "Seven" };

        var OddNumbers = new List<string>();
        var EvenNumbers = new List<string>();
        int i = 0;
        foreach (var item in mod)
        {

            i = i + 1;
            if (i % 2 == 0)
            {
                EvenNumbers.Add(item);
            }
            else
            {
                OddNumbers.Add(item);
            }
        }
}

        // but when you use an index in your loop I find it more readable to use this
        for (var j = 0; j < mod.Length; ++j)
        {
            if (j % 2 == 0)
                 OddNumbers.Add(mod[j]);
            else
                EvenNumbers.Add(mod[j]);
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
int i = 0;
foreach(var item in mod)  //I assume 'mod' is a collection of ints?
{             
    if (i % 2 == 0)
    {
        //Do something with 'item'.
    }
    else 
    {
        //Do something else with 'item'.
    }

    i++;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on your last question, I'm guessing you want to do this:

```
int i = 0; 
foreach(var item in mod) 
{ 
     ..
     // rest of foreach loop here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create two lists and store the numbers depending on their type:

```
List<int> OddNumbers = new List<int>();
List<int> EvenNumbers = new List<int>();
```

then do the following:

```
         foreach(var item in mod) 
         { 
             if (item % 2 == 0)  
             {                   
                EvenNumbers.Add(item);
             } 
             else 
             {
                OddNumbers.Add(item);
             }
         }
```

Comment: Pretty sure that all the numbers are going to be odd in your code sample.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a corrected version of your algoryth that fixes the fact that you'll alway be comparing a value of i = 1 because your declaration of int i was in the loop

```
    int i = 0; 
     foreach(var item in mod)
     {
         i++;
         if (i % 2 == 0) 
         {                  
            //add to list here for even number 
         }
         else
         {
          // add to list here for odd number
         } 
     }
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple `bool` will suffice.

```
var odds = new List<string>();
var evens = new List<string>();

bool odd = true;
foreach (var item in new[] {"one", "two", "three", "four"})
{
    if (odd)
        odds.Add(item);
    else
        evens.Add(item);

    odd = !odd;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want a list with two columns you could use tuples like this.

```
            List<Tuple<List<int>, List<int>>> listTest = new List<Tuple<List<int>, List<int>>>();

            List<int> evenNumber = new List<int>();
            List<int> oddNumber = new List<int>();

            int i = 0;

            foreach (var item in mod)
            {

                if (i % 2 == 0)
                {
                   //add to list here for even number 
                    evenNumber.Add(i);                      
                }

                if (i % 2 != 0)
                {
                    // add to list here for odd number
                    oddNumber.Add(i);  
                }

                i++;
            }
            listTest.Add(Tuple.Create(oddNumber, evenNumber));
```